# Corrigir escrita no txt

Tags: java, io

Estou com um trecho de código que escreve no TXT, ele funciona porém exclui o que estava escrito antes, como faço para que ele **não** substitua o que já estava escrito?

Segue o trecho do código que estou utilizando:

```
public class TestandoEscrita {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream("c:/EscritaUrna.txt");
            Locale locale = new Locale("pt","BR");
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
            out.println("Voto Computado Dia");

            SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' de 'MMMMM' de 'yyyy' - 'HH':'mm'h'",locale);

            out.println(formatador.format(calendar.getTime()));
            out.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Adicione o `Boolean true` ao construtor do `PrintStream`. Ex:

```
public class TestandoEscrita {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream("c:/EscritaUrna.txt", true); // <- aqui
            Locale locale = new Locale("pt","BR");
            GregorianCalendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar(); 
            out.println("Voto Computado Dia");

            SimpleDateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd' de 'MMMMM' de 'yyyy' - 'HH':'mm'h'",locale);

            out.println(formatador.format(calendar.getTime()));
            out.close();

        }
    }
```

Quando você deixa explícito o `true` no construtor tudo que é escrito vai para o final do arquivo e não se sobrepõe aos dados já gravados. Veja mais na documentação do [`PrintStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#PrintStream(java.io.OutputStream,%20boolean)).